# How to - purge a rabbitmq queue using curl

Tags: curl, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, purge, rabbitmqctl

I am checking is there way to purge a rabbitmq queue using curl ? I know using command line, but I am in need of something using curl?

Suggestions/help appreciated

Note : - with this [link](https://cdn.rawgit.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_5_4/priv/www/api/index.html) , I did not get exact curl command to be used

Answer (score 6):

Actually the link you provided does have the info:

> /api/queues/vhost/name/contents
>
> Contents of a queue. DELETE to purge.
>
> Note you can't GET this.

For example:

```
curl -XDELETE -u admin http://localhost:15672/api/queues/%2f/queuetopurge/contents
```

The %2f is to reference the / vhost.

Answer (score 0):

this is the rabbit according to rabbit api documents;

```
curl -i -u guest:guest -H "content-type:application/json" -XDELETE http://localhost:15672/api/queues/%2F/yourQueueName/contents
```